# Are two $W^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ that are Morita equivalent (in the sense of Rieffel) also Morita equivalent in the algebraic sense (as rings)?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, morita-equivalence

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras, I had a question about Morita equivalence for $C^*$-algebras and $W^*$-algebras, I've come across 3 concepts:

- Morita equivalence for $C^*$-algebras: Equivalence of categories of Hermitian modules of $A$ and $B$.
- Strong Morita equivalence for $C^*$-algebras: This is given by the existence of an "$A$-$B$-imprimitivity bimodule" ($A$-$B$-bimodule satisfying certaing conditions).
- Morita equivalence for $W^*$-algebras (as defined by Rieffel in "Morita equivalence for $C^*$-algebras and $W^*$-algebras", this in the case $A$ and $B$ are $W^*$-algebras): This is given by the existence of an "$A$-$B$-equivalence bimodule".

$W^*$-algebras are $C^*$-algebras so what's the difference there? I read somewhere that two $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are strong Morita equivalent if they are Morita equivalent in the traditional algebraic sense (as rings), but I can't find the proof, so I was wondering:

**Are two $W^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ that are Morita equivalent (due to the existence of an equivalence bimodule), also algebraically Morita equivalent (as rings)?**

Anyone have references for this? Are equivalence bimodules and imprimitivity bimodules the same thing? I've seen different definitions of them, some very similar.

Comment: If I remember correctly it is enough to consider the example $\mathbb C$ and $B(H)$, which are Morita equivalent as W* algebras, but not in the sense of C* algebras?!?

Comment: The point is $B(H)$ has non-trivial closed ideals, but the existence of non-trivial closed intervals is invariant under strong Morita equivalence http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01899246#page-1 therefore $B(H)$ and $\mathbb C$ cannot be Strongly Morita equivalent as C*-algebras

Comment: Meyer says (in "Morita equivalence in algebra and geometry", definition 5) that two $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are strongly Morita equivalent if there's an $A$-$B$-equivalence bimodule, Rieffel says (in "Morita equivalence for $C^*$-algebras and $W^*$-algebras", definition 7.5) that two $W^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent if there's an $A$-$B$-equivalence bimodule and the definition of equivalence bimodules in both papers are exactly identical.

Comment: For $W^*$-algebras, the assumptions are a little different: you have an additional normality ($\sigma$-weak continuity) assumption and, on the other hand, only assume *weak* density.

Comment: In order to turn Marcel's comment into an answer to the question, observe that $B(H)$ having a non-trivial ideal (closed or not) implies that $\mathbb C$ cannot be algebraically Morita equivalent to $B(H)$.

Comment: My counterexample was for $C^\ast$ vs. $W^\ast$. In the second case $\mathbb C$ is Morita equivalent to $B(H)$ while in the first case only to $K(H)\subset B(H)$ but not to $B(H)$. This counter example can be found e.g. here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/MeyerMoritaEquivalence.pdf I did not checked if the OPs notions of ME are exactly the one I have in mind and I am in holidays and have mo time to check any details, therefore I did not put it as an answer.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff Sorry for taking so long to get back to you guys, I've been doing some digging around, basically what I want to know is if for any von Neumann algebra $A$ there's some Hilbert space $H$ such that $A$ and $A \overline{\otimes} B(H)$ are Morita equivalent as rings (where $\overline{\otimes}$ is the tensor product of $W^∗$-algebras), or in what cases Morita equivalence as $W^∗$-algebras implies algebraic Morita equivalence, in Rieffel's paper $A$ and $A \overline{\otimes} B(H)$ are Morita equivalent as $W^∗$-algebras.